# Unicode string changes when Unicode data is submitted from Chrome to ASP.Net page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, encoding

I have strange problem with chrome encoding. IE, FF and Chrome encoding is set to UTF-8. When I have a long Unicode string submitted the value received in the server side is totally distorted in Chrome but is OK with FF and IE.

The textarea has a string comprised of characters 768 to 800. The form is submitted. I want to get the same string on the server-side. Distortion of the string happens only in Chrome

Here is the Code

```
&lt;form id="form1" runat="server"&gt;
    &lt;div&gt;
    &lt;textarea id="ta1" runat="server" rows="10" cols="50"&gt;&lt;/textarea&gt;
    &lt;asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" /&gt;
&lt;/form&gt;
&lt;sccript&gt;
    var ta1 = document.getElementById('ta1');
        var s = '';
        for (var i = 768; i &lt; 800; i++)
        {
            s += String.fromCharCode(i);
        }
        ta1.value = s;
&lt;/script&gt;
---------------------
Code behind
--------------------
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

string s = ta1.Value;
string s2 = "";
for(int i=0;i&lt;s.length;i++)
{
   s2 += "i:" + Convert.ToInt32(s[i]) + "&lt;br/&gt;";
}

Response.Write(s2);

}
```

---

The output is 768 to 799 in IE and FF. But completely messed up in Chrome.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the Chrome browser. Please add this, I hope your problem will be resolved.

```
Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```

For a similar issue please see this article http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.com/2009/02/file-upload-not-working-with-update.html

Comment: Nope it did not solve the problem. The code is appearing weird. Add a textarea(ta2) and a button(Button1) to a web form.

Comment: It did not help Here is the code again.var s2 = '';
var ta2 = document.getElementById('ta2');
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
{   
    var c = s.charAt(i);            
    for (var j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++)
    {
        s2 += String.fromCharCode(bytes[j]);
    }
}
ta2.value = s2;
       
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    string s = ta1.Value;string s2 = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        s2 += "i:" + Convert.ToInt32(s[i]) + "<br/>";
    }
    Response.Write(s2);
}